# Javascript error on mobile - not on desktop

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, mobile

My website uses javascript. On computer, it works fine without errors. On my mobile phone, using chrome 40, it does not : using the chrome remote dev tools, I can see the chrome tab console of my phone.

It throws this error :

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` at line 20.

Here is the code around the line 20 :

```
<script>
    function hideUpdateMenu(){
        document.getElementById('updateMenu').style.display = "none";
    }
    function toggleSettingsMenu (){
        let setMenu = document.getElementById('settingsMenu'); // Line 20
        if (setMenu.style.display == "block"){
            setMenu.style.display="none";
        }
        else{
            setMenu.style.display ="block";
        }
    }
```

The same page with the same code works perfectly fine on Windows 10 using chrome.

What can I do ? What could be causing this problem ?

Comment: Seems correct to me, are you sure that there isn't a weird whitespace character there? It happens to me sometimes when i type alt+space it seems like i typed a space but javascript complains about it because it's actually a non-breaking space. Try to rewrite that line maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Chrome 40 on mobiles doesn't support ES6 (and hence it doesn't understand the let keyword). Replace it with var (which shouldn't change the functionality of the code you have posted).

i.e.

```
var setMenu = document.getElementById('settingsMenu');
```

Comment: Hi Nick and welcome to SO. Asking the OP to do something, as in "What happens if you...?" is best suited to be a _comment_; not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've edited the post to be an answer instead of a speculation.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Also, upgrading Chrome worked too. I didn't realize my version was _this_ obsolete.